# How do I automatically change to a specific folder on login for an account with no home folder?

Tags: 12.04, bash, users, bashrc

Typically I would create a user account and in the home folder, place the `cd` command in the `~/.bashrc` file. For system users, however, with on home folders, the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file is used instead and with multiple system users I need a more conditional approach.

Can the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file know which user is executing it, and change directories on login based on which user I've logged in as?

These system users are never logged in as remotely, only using `su`.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the home folder for a user in `/etc/passwd`. Find the line with that user name and change the sixth entry which represents the absolute path to the directory where the user will be in when he log in.

See also: [Understanding /etc/passwd File Format](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/)

Comment: I encounter an issue where in the /etc/password already pointing to /home/user, but when I log in using the user cred, it doesn't redirect me to /home/user. It is still in home/ubuntu. Do you know why?